# 403 Forbidden when loading images from public/image folder laravel vuejs xampp

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, xampp

In my profile the image is displayed perfectly  but I am getting the below error in the console. if i try to access the image from public folder it dose not show me the error but if I try to access it form image folder which is sub folder it shows me the error.anyone can help me with this problem since 4 days I am searching the solution but I did not find any solution yet it will be so kind of him.

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested
>   directory. There is either no index document or the directory is
>   read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403 admin-cms.me Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s PHP/7.1.31

**My API Code is :**

```
Route::get('profile','API\UserController@profile');
```

**My Controller Code is:**

```
 public function profile()
    {
        //
        return auth('api')->user();
    }
```

**My  Data and Methods  Code is:**

```
  data() {
    return {
      users: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: "",
        bio: "",
        photo: ""
      })
    };
  },

methods: {
    getProfilePhoto() {
      return "image/" + this.form.photo;
    }
```

**My HTML Code in profile.vue is:**

```
<div class="widget-user-image">
            <img class="img-circle" :src="getProfilePhoto()" alt="User Avatar" />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `this.form.photo` has a value at the time of `getProfilePhoto()` being called?

The error message:

> There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected

Makes me think `getProfilePhoto()` is returning `'image/' + ''` which results in the image directory attempting to be indexed.

One option would be to only show the profile photo if `this.form.photo` has a value, using `v-if`:

```html
<div class="widget-user-image">
    <img class="img-circle" v-if="form.photo" :src="getProfilePhoto()" alt="User Avatar" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes because on page load I am filling the form and as it is loading the picture is displayed but still getting the error

Comment: Mr.Brice can you tell me what should I do or how should I do it

Comment: I have edited my answer to show a possible way forward: hiding the profile photo until `this.form.photo` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some issue with permissions, do you have access to your public directory, if you do can you check your permissions? ie:

```
ls -li public
```

now check if www-data or nginx have allow-read access permission to your `image` folder.

Comment: Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        11/6/2019  12:31 AM                css
d-----        11/6/2019  12:31 AM                fonts
d-----        11/6/2019   1:19 AM                images
d-r---        11/6/2019  10:16 AM                img

Comment: the main problem is when the image is in public/img it gives me the error if I take it out of the sub folder it wont give me the error

Comment: then the `img` folder isn't accessible, to make sure it can also be publicly accessed you can try and change it's permission:


`sudo chmod ugo+w public/img`

Comment: sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name,